# No wlan0 or wired connection at all crunchbang

Tags: linux, networking

I have a really big issue, I went and bought a Lenovo ideapad 110 today and the first thing I did was replace the windows OS with Crunchbang 11. My problem is that I have tried every modprobe command, if config up, rfkill, iwconfig up, and neither the wireless or wired connections are being picked up by the OS. So I have absolutely no Internet accessibility at the current moment at all. I have been working on this problem all day and have not found a solution to get the wireless or at least wired connection to work. The computer doesn't even show the wlan0 option under ifconfig I have no Internet to install outside packages that come beyond what the OS comes with. Am I missing something? The wireless card is a Realtek but again the network manager shows nothing to connect to and the wired connection is grayed out unallowing me to even click it. I have tried editing all those files directly still nothing.

Comment: I wonder if the hardware simply isn't supported. Crunchbang development ended [two years ago](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=38916) and If the repositories are gone, you can't download additional packages

Answer (score 1):

Crunchbang 11 is very old. It was based on Debian 7, which was released in 2012. When I tried it in 2012/2013, it came with Linux 3.2 by default. The Current Debian Stable (Jessie, version 8, released in 2014) comes with Linux 3.16, whereas the next Stable (Stretch, version 9) will probably use Linux 4.9 or later.

According to [this](http://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=38024.0) post, the Ideapad 110 has the following network controllers:

```
Realtek RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  driver: rtl8821ae
Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
  driver: r8169
```

Now, [this](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22) Debian wiki article states that Debian 7/Wheezy, the parent distribution of Crunchbang 11, does not support *rtl8821ae*, but Debian 8/Jessie does. However, even the latest Debian stable does not support *r8169*.

In conclusion, Crunchbang 11 is incompatible with your laptop because it is too old. You should move on to something much more up-to-date.

Comment: That's unfortunate I love crunchbang! Thank you I can stop pulling my hair out over the issue!